# On click x remove class on y

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to close (remove class .active) when clicking on .btn.

There probably is a conflict because also clicking on .item.

It only works on clicking on an other .item.

```js
$(".item").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

//$(".btn").on("click", function(){
//  $(".item").removeClass("active");
//});

$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent(".item").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

.wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #f00;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item.active {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.large {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.active .large {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.active .close {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 1</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 2</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 3</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 4</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 5</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 6</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 7</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you are using query selectors on classes, if you have multiple elements with that class it will remove the class active from all of them (referring to your .item on click)

Comment: why are both add and removeclass at the same time

Comment: @RyanWilson I think that's on purpose. Only one `.item` should be active at any one time, so the OP removes the `active` class from all, then adds to the clicked-on `.item`.

Comment: Simply because I don't know what I'm doing. It works but can't get the btn to remove the active class

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ah, got it. Thanks Mike

Comment: where to add class active and where to remove class active, need classfiraction

Comment: @RyanWilson When clicking on an other item the old active one needs to close so you an't have 2 open.

Comment: @Marc ok. Now that that is clarified, I removed the fiddle from above. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action in one of the buttons, otherwise both actions will be executed (the opener and the close action). Return `false` on any jQuery event will prevent default action and stop propagation of the event.

Check my example, i changed the close button action to the `span.close` elements:

```js
$(".item").on("click", function(){
  $(".item").not($(this)).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

$(".close").on("click", function(){
  $(this).closest(".item.active").removeClass("active");
  return false;
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; transition:0.5s; margin:0; padding:0;}
.clear{clear:both; height:0;}
.wrap{padding:20px; background:#eee; color:#fff;}

.btn{display:block; line-height:100px; position:relative; z-index:100; font-size:14px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;}
.btn:hover{background:#f00;}

.item{position:relative; float:left; margin:2px; width:100px; height:100px; text-align:center; background:purple; overflow:hidden;}
.item.active{overflow:visible; width:200px; height:200px;}

.large{width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity:0;}
.active .large{width:200px; height:200px; background:red; opacity:1; z-index:10;}

.close{position:absolute; opacity:0; right:8px; bottom:8px; width:16px; height:16px; text-align:center; background:black; cursor:pointer; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px;}
.active .close{opacity:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 1</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 2</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 3</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
 
   <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 4</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 5</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 6</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h2 class="btn">item 7</h2>
    <div class="large">
      <span class="close">x</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, thank you! I just noticed I was talking about btn to close it but I meant the .close button.

Comment: Great, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the bubbling of the event to the parent "item". Use `event.stopPropagation`:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(e){
      $(this).parent(".item").removeClass("active");
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Of course the way you designed it, the parent will never receive the clicks..

Comment: When I use this it won't open. #EDIT# sorry, I meant .close not .btn

Comment: yes because the parent does not receive it anymore. Here is working one: https://jsfiddle.net/pngpkq46/10/

Comment: Thx, but I need that to work on the .close and not closing when clicking on the .btn. 
When I change .btn to .close it won't work because its not .parent but .parent.parent. (ps that was my fault) See the example muecas made, thats what I like to achive.

Comment: Add a similar handler to the ".close" span  as well: https://jsfiddle.net/pngpkq46/15/

Answer (score 0):

What about a toggling approach?

```
$(".item").on("click", function(){
    $(".item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hw15pq6c/1/

Comment: Looks pritty clean but its possible to open 2 or more at the same time.

Comment: @Marc It's just 1 extra line to remove active from any current items before toggling it on the targeted item. Edited snippet